# how to hide scrollbar even if div is not larger then max-height

Tags: html, css

i have a div named panel, CSS of whose is

[image]

```
.msg_panel
{
width:100px;
height:45px;
max-height:200px;
padding: 3px;
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

now even if height of panel is not larger than the max-height, i am getting the scrollbar visible(you can see in the pic).
I want scrollbar visible only if max-height is attained.

i tried javascript, but can it be done only in css

Comment: Well you have `overflow-y:scroll`! Change to `overflow-y:hidden`

Comment: @LeeTaylor No, he want the scrollbar when it reach the max-height, not hide the overflow...

Mukur: You want the box to resize in the y axis until reaching max-height right? (And then have the scrollbar appearing)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Set the `overflow-y` property to `auto`

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/TLwcX/1/

Answer (score 5):

Set  overflow-y to auto which removes the vertical scroll and it will appear only if the content exceeds your max-height of 200px...

```
.msg_panel
{
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have explicitly stated that you need vertical scroll always visible: `overflow-y: scroll;`

To let browser decide when to show the scroll use this: `overflow-y: auto;`